# iPhone Development over VPN

Tags: iphone, xcode, vpn, development

I am going to bring a Raspberry Pi with me to uni so I don't have to carry in my MacBook Pro. I'm setting up a home server which I will connect to over VPN (to my house) from my Pi and Phone.

When testing on 4G, I am able to ping my computer on my WiFi by connecting my phone to my own VPN. However despite this, I cannot debug wirelessly through XCode which I would like to.

How can I wirelessly develop iPhone apps with my MacBook Pro being at home and my iPhone connected to a VPN connection to my house?

*Edit:*
If it helps, the VPN is enabled via a Nighthawk router.

Comment: What happens when you try to "debug wirelessly through xcode"?